# I can't apply any modifier to my animation channel

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor, fcurves

This is blender 2.9.

I'm trying to loop an animation using the cycles modifier but I can't add it to all axis, as you can see on the images below.

It only worked for the z-axis, and it didn't work in the x-axis. In the modifier tab it shows that it is greyed out. I tried adding another cycles modifier but it says "modifier could not be added(see console for details)" as shown in the third image.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 3):

You accidentally disabled the f-curves modifier on this channel. It's the wrench icon. Click on it to enable it.

[image]

Comment: bro ur a legend i know rookie mistake but thanks so much